# How to ckeck what oracle databases instances are running in a docker linux container?

Tags: docker, oracle11g

How can I check which Oracle databases instances are running in a docker container?

Comment: Titles are meant to be summaries, the question should go in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The question title is quite not enough to understand your question. We need more detailled information: What is your environment? Which software is used? What are you trying? ... Without those information, it's not possible to give an answear that exactly fit your problem. I'll try to give you some help anyway, but you should clarify your question.

In general, the concept of Docker is to have a single So there shouldn't be multiple instances in a well designed container. Depending on what software you have and what information you want to receive, look in the `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose` files.

If you don't have access to them and the container are running on a system you have access to, a shell inside the container may help. Use `docker ps` to find out the name of the desired container. Then use `docker exec -it <container-name> sh` to get an interactive shell in those container. You'll recognize that your command promt will change to another host if this worked:

```
root@nashost:~# docker exec -it mariadb bash
root@0c4481588ffe:/#
```

`0c4481588ffe` is the container id. You can now execute commands inside the container like `ps` to find out which processes are running:

```
root@0c4481588ffe:/# ps -guax
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
mysql        1  0.0  0.9 2978584 322248 ?      Ssl  Mar12   5:51 mysqld
root       620  0.0  0.0  18508  2296 ?        Ss   18:34   0:00 bash
root       636  0.0  0.0  34400  1804 ?        R+   18:34   0:00 ps -guax
```

We can also use CLI tools that allow us to query the database (like showing all existing databases, tables and so on):

```
root@0c4481588ffe:/# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

This example is from MariaDB (MySQL fork), since I don't have a Oracle database on my test machine. But you can do [something similar with CLI tools from Oracle](http://www.spiegel.de/wirtschaft/soziales/kirchen-nehmen-erneut-mehr-steuern-ein-a-1065976.html).